# hello i am trying to call method in a string but i am facing error method invocation may produce

Tags: java, android, methods

i am trying to call a method in string from sharedpreference but when i am calling i am facing method invocation getText may produce 'nullpointerexception' warning

```
public class RetrofitClient  {
   
        Sharedpreference sharedpreference;
        private final  String token = sharedpreference.getTEXT();
```

following is my sharedpreference code from where i am calling my method getText where i returning a string which is TEXT

```
  public class Sharedpreference  {
        
        public static String TEXT = "text";
        public static final String Otp = "1234";
        
     SharedPreferences prefs;
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    
    public Sharedpreference(Context context){
        prefs=context.getSharedPreferences("App_key",0);
        editor=prefs.edit();
        editor.apply();
    }
   public  void setTEXT(String prize) {
    
            editor.putString(TEXT,prize);
            editor.commit();
    
        }
    
        public  String getTEXT() {
            return prefs.getString(TEXT,"");
        }
        public  void setotp(String otp) {
    
            editor.putString("otp",otp);
            editor.commit();
    
        }
        public  String getotp() {
            return prefs.getString("otp","");
        }
    
     }
```

Comment: Also paste the code of `SharedPreferences` class.

Comment: i had already paste sharepreference code and i want to call getText method in RetrofitClient class where i am facing warning and my app is crashing

Comment: In which line you get the NPE? Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names should start with uppercase character and method names should be camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of `Sharedpreference` inside `RetrofitClient` class.

Eg:

```
Sharedpreference sharedpreference = new Sharedpreference(...)
String token = sharedpreference.getTEXT();
```

Comment: i already tried it is saying  that unknown class sharedpreference